# ASP.NET Application-state provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I've so far implemented several custom multi-tenant providers for Azure Table Store like a ASP.NET Session-state provider, ASP.NET Virtual Path Provider, a.s.f. I would now like to implement a custom multi-tenant [ASP.NET Application-State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594(v=vs.100).aspx) provider, but I have not found any resources or best practices online.

In the example below I show how I would like to use the ASP.NET Application-State provider to keep track of number of online users across all my Azure Web application nodes:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application["NumOnlineUsers"] = ((int)Application["NumOnlineUsers"] + 1);
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application["NumOnlineUsers"] = ((int)Application["NumOnlineUsers"] - 1);
}
```

How can I implement a ASP.NET Application-State Provider where I persist the application-state data in the Azure Table Store?

Comment: I hope you don't depend on this being accurate... because it will never be.. there are many situations where Session_End will never get called, such as when an app pool is recycled.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch That is just one of the ways I want to use the custom ASP.NET Application-State provider, thanks for noticing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in your question states the following assumptions about `ApplicationState`:

- **Volatility:** Because application state is **stored in server memory**, it is lost whenever the application is stopped or restarted.
- **Resources:** Because it is **stored in memory**, application state is very fast compared to saving data to disk or a database.
- **Scalability:** Application state is **not shared** among multiple servers serving the same application

A provider like you suggested would change the volatility (because the data would live elsewhere and could be restored), as well as enable scalability (because multiple `ApplicationState`s could then share the values). However it comes at the cost of the simplicity that that page suggests for `ApplicationState`.

In short, it sounds like .NET intended for this data structure to hold values necessary for a single instance of an application that did not need to persist across process restarts. If you are using it in that sense, it may be worth considering a different data structure than `ApplicationState` rather than bending through hoops to make it something it was not envisioned to be. Even if you did manage to write the persistence layer, think about the last point they bring up:

- **Concurrency:** Application state is free-threaded, which means that application state data can be **accessed simultaneously by many threads**.

How do you support that when you introduce the lag and fallibility involved with talking to an Azure table, presumably on another virtual machine or at least on a different process? What happens when thread 1 makes a change to a value, then thread 2 changes it back, but the change from thread 2 gets written to disk first then thread 1? After reboot, you would have no idea what the expected value would be.

In short, I don't think you should write it. It's not a tool that is needed, and breaks intended use (although that alone is not enough to say it shouldn't be written). The final nail in the coffin is that it's not feasible because Microsoft did not expose the same granularity for extending it that they did with the `SessionStateProvider` class.

Comment: *Resources* I can handle with in-memory caching, I have already implemented this pattern successfully with the other providers. *Volatility* can be solved by reading from the storage when the application starts. *Concurrency* is not _that_ important for us as we can handle some errors -its not business-critical data we're storing. *Scalability*; well it will be shared if we get a Application-state provider up and working.

Comment: I'm saying that you are fixing things that were not meant to be fixed. The parts I highlighted in bold indicate limitations intended for application-state because it is not supposed to be a durable data-store. If it were, what reason would there be for a database? Or a session? By "fixing" these things, you turn application-state into a provider like the others you have mentioned, but for what reason?  App-state is meant to be limited, and different from the other providers. Simpler, not more complex.